# Using @PreAuthorize on SpringData repositories

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to secure Spring-Data repositories by using @PreAuthorize annotations on the my repository interface (since most methods are inherited) so that all methods get secured.
The result is that any custom methods included in my interface get security by all methods inherited by Spring-Data interfaces are not.
Applying the same thing on a simple component interface extending a superinterface will work properly.
I am not sure whether this is a Spring-Security or Spring-Data issue. I would appreciate some help figuring this out.
An example with unit tests for the working service setup and the non working Spring-Data repository can be downloaded at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133083-Using-PreAuthorize-on-SpringData-repositories. The failing testSuperRepositoryWithUser should get an AccessDeniedException, but the @PreAuthorize annotation does not apply on the JpaRepository interface.

Comment: The same issue also applies when security is enabled using protect-pointcut in the xml configuration.

Comment: Do you have "normal" case (Repository1.findAll() and Repository2.findAll() have different list of allowed roles) or simplified one (all findAll() methods of all repositories have the same list of allowed roles)?

Answer (score 1):

By default spring wraps beans with JDK proxies. In this case annotations will work only for interface methods. So you need some more powerfull proxies (CGlib or AspectJ).  I am not sure that it will fix your case "as is". You can try for CGlib:

```
<security:global-method-security ... proxy-target-class="true" />
```

For AspectJ:

```
<security:global-method-security ... mode="aspectj" />
```

In both cases you will need additional libraries and additional configuration.
See [AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) for additional details.

From architectural point of view best place for security annotations is on your service methods.  Consider following case: you have ServiceA.methodA() and ServiceB.methodB(). They use RepositoryC.methodC().  Your client want different security permissions for methodA() and methodB(). It will be impossible if your security layer is applied to repositories. So just apply your security annotations to services and there is no problem at all.

Comment: I have tried cglib but it will not work. AspectJ is not an option as it works on concrete classes. Agreed on the architectural point but in my case I want to expose the repository IF an an OSGI service and have control over who (user or service) calls it. Without the ability to secure the repository methods directly I have to bundle it together with a service that will expose and secure the same methods which is a minor inconvienience as I will have to duplicate the methods spring-data generated for me on the service IF.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `@PreAuthorize` or similar annotations on all methods of a `Repository` interface by applying it to the interface and not the methods.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERUSER')")
public interface PersonnelRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>{}
```

You can also provide an annotation on a base repository that others inherit from which will secure the methods of inherited repositories.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@RepositoryRestResource()
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')") 
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>{}
```

Now this repository will have the same security on all of it's methods as well.

```
public interface FooRepo extends BaseRepository <Foo, Long> {}
```